# How do I get AWK to reaarrange and manipulate text in a file to two output files depending on conditions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I  tried to find an efficient way to split then recombine text in one file into two seperate files. it's got a lot going on like removing the decimal point, reversing the sign (+ becomes - and - becomes +) in amount field and padding. For example:

INPUT file `input.txt`:

(this first line is there just to give character position more easily instead of counting, it's not present in the input file, the "|" is just there to illustrate position only)

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
           |         |             |     |               |                    |     |  ("|" shows position)
123456789XXPPPPPPPPPP              NNNNNN#1404.58        #0.00                0     1
987654321YYQQQQQQQQQQ              NNNNNN#-97.73         #-97.73              1     1
777777777XXGGGGGGGGGG              NNNNNN#115.92         #115.92              0     0
888888888YYHHHHHHHHHH              NNNNNN#3.24           #3.24                1     0
```

Any line that contains a "1" as the 85th character above goes to one file say `OutputA.txt` rearranged like this:

```
PPPPPPPPPP~~NNNNNN123456789XX~~~-0000140458-0000000000
QQQQQQQQQQ~~NNNNNN987654321YY~~~+0000009773+0000009773
```

As well as any line that contains a "0" as the 85th character above goes to another file `OutputB.txt` rearranged like this:

```
GGGGGGGGGG~~NNNNNN777777777XX~~~-0000011592-0000011592
HHHHHHHHHH~~NNNNNN888888888YY~~~-0000000324-0000000324
```

It seems so complicated, but if I could just grab each portion of the input lines as different variables and then write them out in a different order with right alignment for the amount padded with 0s and splitting them into different files depending on the last column. Not sure how I can put all these things together in one go.

I tried printing out each line into a different file depending whether the 85th charater is a 1 or 0, then then trying to create variables say from first character to 11th character is varA and the next 10 is varB etc... but it get complex quickly because I need to change + to - and - to + and then pad with zeros and change te spacing. it gets a bit mad. This should be possible with one script but I just can't put all the pieces together.

I've looked for tutorials but nothing seems to cover grabbing based on condition whilst at the same time padding, rearranging, splitting etc.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: please update the question to show your coding attempt(s) along with the (wrong) output generated by your code

Answer (score 1):

> split

Use GNU `AWK` ability to [`print` to file](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html), consider following simple example

```
seq 20 | awk '$1%2==1{print $0 > "fileodd.txt"}$1%2==0{print $0 > "fileeven.txt"}'
```

which does read output of `seq 20` (numbers from 1 to 20, inclusive, each on separate line) and does put odd numbers to `fileodd.txt` and even number to `fileeven.txt`

> recombine text

Use [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) and string contatenation for that task, consider following simple example, say you have `file.txt` with DD-MM-YYYY dates like so

```
01-29-2022
01-30-2022
01-31-2022
```

but you want YYYY-MM-DD then you could do that by

```
awk '{print substr($0,7,4) "-" substr($0,1,2) "-" substr($0,4,2)}' file.txt
```

which gives output

```
2022-01-29
2022-01-30
2022-01-31
```

`substr` arguments are: string (`$0` is whole line), start position and length, space is concatenation operator.

> removing the decimal point

Use [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) with second argument set to empty string to delete unwanted characters, but keep in mind `.` has special meaning in regular expression, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
100.15
200.30
300.45
```

then

```
awk '{gsub(/[.]/,"");print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
10015
20030
30045
```

Observe that `/[.]/` not `/./` is used and `gsub` does change in-place.

> reversing the sign(...)padding

Multiply by -1, then use `sprintf` with [suitable modifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html), consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
1
-10
100
```

then

```
awk '{print "Reversed value is " sprintf("%+05d",-1*$1)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Reversed value is -0001
Reversed value is +0010
Reversed value is -0100
```

Explanation: `%` - this is place where value will be instered, `+` - prefix using `-` or `+`, `05` - pad with leading zeros to width of 5 characters, `d` assume value is integer. `sprintf` does return formatted string which can be concatenated with other string as shown above.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thanks for that comprehensive answer. I think I can put this altogether to make it all work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this task:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='
123456789XXPPPPPPPPPP              NNNNNN#1404.58        #0.00                0     1
987654321YYQQQQQQQQQQ              NNNNNN#-97.73         #-97.73              1     1
777777777XXGGGGGGGGGG              NNNNNN#115.92         #115.92              0     0
888888888YYHHHHHHHHHH              NNNNNN#3.24           #3.24                1     0
'

convert() {
  jq -rR --arg lineSelector "$1" '
  def transformNumber($len):
    tonumber |                                    # convert string to number
    (if . < 0 then "+" else "-" end) as $sign |   # store inverted sign
    if . < 0 then 0 - . else . end |              # abs(number)
    . * 100 |                                     # number * 100
    tostring |                                    # convert number back to string
    $sign + "0" * ($len - length) + .;            # indent with leading zeros

  # Main program
    split(" ") |                                  # split each line by space
    map(select(length > 0)) |                     # remove empty entries
    select(.[4] == $lineSelector) |               # keep only lines with the selected value in last column

    # generate output                               # example for first line
    .[0][11:21] +                                   # PPPPPPPPPP
    "~~" +                                          # ~~
    (.[1] | split("#")[0]) +                        # NNNNNN
    .[0][0:11] +                                    # 123456789XX
    "~~~" +                                         # ~~~
    (.[1] | split("#")[1] | transformNumber(10)) +  # -0000140458
    (.[2] | split("#")[1] | transformNumber(10))    # -0000000000
  ' <<< "$2"
}

convert 0 "$INPUT"   # or convert 1 "$INPUT"
```

**Output for `0`**

```
GGGGGGGGGG~~NNNNNN777777777XX~~~-0000011592-0000011592
HHHHHHHHHH~~NNNNNN888888888YY~~~-0000000324-0000000324
```

**Output for `1`**

```
PPPPPPPPPP~~NNNNNN123456789XX~~~-0000140458-0000000000
QQQQQQQQQQ~~NNNNNN987654321YY~~~+0000009773+0000009773
```